# Simplest way to continously send XML data in QTcpSocket

Tags: c++, qt, networking, network-programming, qtcpsocket

I have to send continuously xml data from my pc to my tablet. (the both are running windows)

My tablet should receive the complete xml file and show it in real time.

The xml file is composed of a notification message each time it is sent.
It is of type:

```
<notification>
<id>1</id>
<message>hello world</message>
</notification>
```

Which is the simplest way to do it using QTcpSocket?

Comment: Will you send the never-ending-stream as a single XML document, or will it be a continuous *connection* that you send multiple XML documents over?

Comment: Besides my previous query, TCP is a *streaming* protocol. The start of the stream is when the connection is accepted, the end when the connection closes. In between that there is no message boundaries, it's just an endless stream of data.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: I read that I should care about the sent data. Because data are not sent completely, It could be truncated in multiple packet. which need to implement a protocol to be sure of reading the complete xml file.

Comment: That's the *streaming* part, since it's streaming there is no message boundaries. You must overlay the stream with your own protocol, that either includes specific boundaries or have a header containing the length of the message. That's why I asked you about the XML documents. A single XML document without end is very hard to parse, but if you send smaller XML documents you have your messages and message boundaries in the beginning and end of the XML document. There's no need to close the connection between the messages, just let them flow through the stream.

Comment: Yes, how to be sure for example of sending and receiving successfully an xml file of type: <data>string data</data>

Comment: Parse the stream, continuously.

Comment: I wrote a example of the notification message sent each time.

Comment: AS Joachim suggests you simply accept all data and continuously parse it. Lets say that you are looking for data between two tags <start of message> and </end of message>, then you would keep reading any incoming data until you see the first tag (I guess you would discard anything before that as erroneous). Then when you get the start tag, open your file and store all data into your file until you read in the end tag and then close your file and start scanning for the start tag again...

Comment: @code_fodder: yes, clear, very useful.

Comment: your comments are useful. you can post an answer so that I can upvote it and tick it.

Comment: Give it a go, if you get stuck post up your code attempt.

Comment: @ProEns08 ah, that's good of you, sir. I have posted it in a slightly nicer answer format.

Comment: @code_fodder: you were fast. Ok, thank you.

Comment: @ProEns08 lol, when there are points going, I don't hand around!... I am only here for the points, and badges :p

Comment: you merit them, by the way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply accept all data and continuously parse it.

Lets say that you are looking for data between two tags:

```
<notification>
      :
    data 
      :
</notification>
```

Then you would do the following:

- keep reading any incoming data until you see the first tag (I guess you would discard anything before that as erroneous).
- When you get the start tag, open your file and start storing all data into your file and start scanning for the end tag.
- When you read in the end tag and then close your file and start scanning for the start tag again (i.e. go back to the start state)...

You just need to make a little state machine (probably just need a variable with two states: `SCANNING_FOR_START` and `STORING_DATA_AND_SCANNING_FOR_END`).

Comment: Thank you, +1. for the answer.